# How do I sort by node authored on date?

Tags: 7, views

In Drupal 7, I have created a view to show a list of nodes I need to sort by node authored on date.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Will the "Post date" field work for you? Every node has this date automatically added when first saved with this date by default.

Answer (score 1):

In your view, go to section: SORT CRITERIA.
Add field "Content: Post date" 
Sort ascending or Sort descending.

Answer (score 0):

[!This is a picture of Views UI]

Edit the View and go to (SORT CRITERIA) and Checked (**Content: Post date**)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xq2F.png